# in PHP - Is it possible to combine/concatenate several gzencode

Tags: php, http, caching, gzip

I have a large page that downloads in gzip encoding.
The portion of the file that changes between viewers is tiny.
Idealy I'd like to gzencode() the large static piece and cache it, then combine it with a gzencoded version of the more dynamic stuff. Is this possible? If not, is there any other trick I could use to still serve this page gzencoded and in 1 request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>No. Neither the gzip format nor the deflate encoding allow for blocks to be concatenated together. And there is no built-in function in PHP to do so.</s>

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The gzip specification, [RFC 1952](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1952), specifically states that concatenation is part of the format. "A gzip file consists of a series of "members" (compressed data sets).  The format of each member is specified in the following section.  The members simply appear one after another in the file, with no additional information before, between, or after them."

Comment: I shall not dispute the expert. (Albeit in defense: this was probably based on confounding gzcompress [zlib format] for gzencode. And back when there was no gzdecode for true GZIP-format decompression - prior PHP 5.4 that is. / Come to think of it, that might have been part of my complainy lobbying.)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it works just fine. I just tested it. It's even documented (sort of) in the gzip man page.

Multiple  compressed  files  can  be concatenated. In this case, gunzip
will extract all members at once. For example:

```
     gzip -c file1  > foo.gz
     gzip -c file2 >> foo.gz
```

Then

```
     gunzip -c foo
```

is equivalent to

```
     cat file1 file2
```

So in PHP you can call gzencode() multiple times. Like such:

```
   $string1 = "test1";
   $string2 = "test2";
   $output = gzencode($string1).gzencode($string2);
```

Sorry to necro the post, but this comes up on google for an unrelated search and wanted to correct the answer.